# can't segue programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to segue from one uiviewcontroller to another under program control
I have created two view controllers in storyboard and created a modal segue between them

when i call this method

```
 - (void)segueMethod {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"thisone" sender: nil];
}
```

i get this message  Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

also when i try to trigger the segue with a unbutton i get this message:
Warning: Attempt to present  on  while a presentation is in progress!

I'm baffled and I think this use to work in preview versions????

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: That error means that the controller where you have that code doesn't have its view in the hierarchy. From where in the code are you calling that method?

Comment: well i don't know i'm just adding two view controllers from the storyboard.

Comment: What do you mean you don't know? You wrote the code didn't you? Where do you call segueMethod?

Comment: Do you not understand the question? Somewhere in your code, you have to have [self segueMethod] for that method to run. Where did you put that?

Comment: Yes I wrote the code and I understand the question.  I call the [self segueMethod] further down in the code when I decide that I need to segue.  Interestingly, that method works fine when called from viewdidappear, but nowhere else

Comment: Is the place where you put it, called before viewDidAppear? That would be my guess from the error message. If so, you can't do that. The controller's view needs to be on screen first. Why it would give you an error when calling it from a button is a mystery though.

Comment: no, it's after viewdidappear.  this must be an ios6 thing because it's worked for me in the past. I'm truly stumped.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. If it works in viewDidAppear, then it should work in any method that's called after that. Also, the fact that you get that other error if you put the method in a button, tells me that there might be something setup wrong. Are you somehow dismissing your current view before trying to segue?

Answer (score 0):

You may be using some code previous to iOS 5. I suggest you check the way you add your root view controller to the main window.

Comment: Ok. But you checked the way you're adding your root view controller to the main window?

Comment: what do you suggest I check for?  I'm just dragging two view controllers onto the storyboard. Thankds

Comment: And one of your view controllers is the initial view controller?